# Installing Python or PyQGIS for QGIS-Android

Tags: qgis-android

Is it possible to install python-plugins on QGIS-Android? What are the steps for installing it? I am assuming that just like on Linux the package PyQGIS is needed?

I am using this version of QGIS-Android:

- http://qgis.org/downloads/android/qgis-release.apk

System: Google Nexus 7 (2012)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not currently supported. There is work in this area though.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Just bought a used tablet to use as a mobile mapping computer. I still have a lot to figure out. But I already love to have QGIS on Android.

Comment: @Nathan W, any update on when QGIS Android will support python plugins?